# Google analytics no http respsonse detected

Tags: html, google-analytics, analytics

Google analytics isn't tracking my site data.

The chrome Tag Assistant extension shows me this error

[image]

And here is my page head -

```
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <!-- Main Information -->
  <title>Jordan Miguel</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Portfolio for Front-End developer
        and designer Jordan Miguel">
  <meta name="keywords" content="jordan miguel web design development
        london UX">
  <meta name="author" content="Jordan Miguel">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <!-- "Website" -->
  <meta property="og:url" content="">
  <meta property="og:title" content="Jordan Miguel">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
        minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Fav and touch icons -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <!-- Plugins -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.typeit/4.4.0/typeit.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js" defer></script>
  <script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" async defer></script>
  <!-- Style -->
  <style type="text/css">.tk-freight-big-pro{font-family:"freight-big-pro",sans-serif;}</style>
  <style type="text/css">
  @font-face{font-family:freight-big-pro;src:url(https://use.typekit.net/af/5220ee/0000000000000000000132c1/27/l?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n7&v=3) 
    format("woff2"),url(https://use.typekit.net/af/5220ee/0000000000000000000132c1/27/d?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n7&v=3) 
    format("woff"),url(https://use.typekit.net/af/5220ee/0000000000000000000132c1/27/a?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n7&v=3) 
    format("opentype");font-weight:700;font-style:normal;}@font-face{font-family:freight-big-pro;src:url(https://use.typekit.net/af/cf14b7/0000000000000000000132c2/27/l?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=i7&v=3) 
    format("woff2"),url(https://use.typekit.net/af/cf14b7/0000000000000000000132c2/27/d?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=i7&v=3) 
    format("woff"),url(https://use.typekit.net/af/cf14b7/0000000000000000000132c2/27/a?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=i7&v=3) 
    format("opentype");font-weight:700;font-style:italic;}@font-face{font-family:freight-big-pro;src:url(https://use.typekit.net/af/2668d3/0000000000000000000132c3/27/l?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n4&v=3) 
    format("woff2"),url(https://use.typekit.net/af/2668d3/0000000000000000000132c3/27/d?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n4&v=3) format("woff"),url(https://use.typekit.net/af/2668d3/0000000000000000000132c3/27/a?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=n4&v=3) 
    format("opentype");font-weight:400;font-style:normal;}@font-face{font-family:freight-big-pro;src:url(https://use.typekit.net/af/af0e9d/0000000000000000000132c4/27/l?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=i4&v=3) 
    format("woff2"),url(https://use.typekit.net/af/af0e9d/0000000000000000000132c4/27/d?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=i4&v=3) format("woff"),url(https://use.typekit.net/af/af0e9d/0000000000000000000132c4/27/a?primer=7cdcb44be4a7db8877ffa5c0007b8dd865b3bbc383831fe2ea177f62257a9191&fvd=i4&v=3) 
    format("opentype");font-weight:400;font-style:italic;}

  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/framework.css" type="text/css">

  <script>
     (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)
    {i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
     (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new 
    Date();a=s.createElement(o),
     m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)
    [0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
     })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-
    analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-80642122-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</head>
```

The strange thing is that I've used this exact structure on multiple sites and I've tried following all of the steps via google.

Comment: Maybe you have some sort of adblocker that prevents the Google network request from being sent ?

Comment: Correct! I disabled my adblocker (uBlock origin) and now I can see real time data. Thanks, make a question so I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Either the script is missing or an ad blocker is blocking it.